# Проблема с сетью в Ubuntu Mini

Tags: linux, сеть, wifi, dhcp, ethernet

Мне нужен **Linux без X** (без графической оболочки, только консоль).
Поставил *Ubuntu Mini*, при выборе ПО всё по-умолчанию оставил. Но к сожалению к сети Интернет не подключается.
Пробовал настроить через **/etc/network/interfaces**, как советуется в Интернете, не помогло. Ни проводной, ни Wi-Fi не работает. В Mint, Ubuntu всё нормально работает.

В упомянутом файле указал получать по DHCP адреса у роутера, то есть

```
auto ...
iface ... inet dhcp
```

после сделал

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему? В чём может быть дело? Может дистрибутив другой посоветуете? Или настройки какие ещё нужно сделать?

Вывод ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <6 чисел №1> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <6 чисел №2> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Если нужен Linux без графической оболочки (для серверных целей), и никаких других ограничений нет, то можно попробовать [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).

Comment: **Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?** Ну Вы, хотя бы, показали, что выдаёт ifconfig, что в системном логе по поводу сети... В чём проблема то? Каков текст сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: Какой демон у вас отвечает за сеть ?

Comment: @Sergey, *что выдаёт ifconfig* — [добро пожаловать в двадцать первый век](https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=129712). пакет *net-tools* (или аналог) в актуальных версиях дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux* уже даже и не ставится по умолчанию. уже семнадцать лет спрашивать имеет смысл: «**что выдаёт `ip a`**»

Comment: @insolor, нужен без графической оболочки и с минимумом лишних пакетов, сервер не нужен, нужен только плеер, файловый менеджер

Comment: @Sergey, ifconfig-а нет, ну или запрятан где :) В чём проблема? apt например не может обновить систему. Кстати сеть была при установке, но когда всё установилось - сети нет, странно как то

Comment: @matz, не знаю, а как проверить?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а почему кстати так? Я тоже заметил что всё как-то меняется в сторону запутанности. Вот чем не устраивал разработчиков eth0?

Comment: @tonchikp, *а почему кстати так?* — в четвёртом по счёту комментарии из преведённой ссылки есть ссылка «[немного истории](https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=126819&st=0&p=1170457&#entry1170457)». *Я тоже заметил что всё как-то меняется в сторону запутанности. Вот чем не устраивал разработчиков eth0?* — а вот это не имеет никакого отношения ни к программе *linux* вообще, ни к его сетевой подсистеме в частности. это [привет от г-на **поттеринга**](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

Comment: по теме: попробуйте не `auto enp3s0`, а `allow-hotplug enp3s0`. после внесения изменений отключите и включите интерфейс: `$ sudo ifdown enp3s0; sudo ifup enp3s0`, и если команда что-нибудь выведет, приложите к вопросу. // и, да, не стоит ли у вас что-нибудь из «хозяйства» *network-manager*-а? я бы рекомендовал в вашей систуации удалить эти пакеты.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вроде бы нету

Comment: @tonchikp **В чём проблема? apt например не может обновить систему** Здесь возможно три варианта: 1) У Вас неправильно настроен список репозитариев. Можете его показать тут? 2) У Вас вообще нет сети. Можете показать состояние сети? Любым способом - *ip, ifconfig, netstat* 3)  У Вас нет доступа в интернет.  - шлюз не пускает. Можете сделать что-то вроде *ping google.com* ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin - По всей видимости, дистрибуторы Ubuntu и OpenSuse живут всё ещё в ХХ веке... Ну - тупые!!!

Comment: @Sergey, **1) У Вас неправильно настроен список репозитариев. Можете его показать тут?** тогда уж не у меня, а у создателей Ubuntu, потому что я всё оставил по-умолчанию **3) У Вас нет доступа в интернет. - шлюз не пускает. Можете сделать что-то вроде ping google.com ?** Дело не в шлюзе, в настройках компьютера про который речь идёт, потому что даже на этом компьютере связь есть во время установки, но когда всё установится - уже её нет

Comment: @Sergey, **2) У Вас вообще нет сети. Можете показать состояние сети? Любым способом - ip, ifconfig, netstat** ifconfig - нету в Mini (сам удивлён), вывод ip в первом сообщении

Comment: @tonchikp Попробуйте нечто вроде: *ip link enp3s0 set  up* И после этого  опять проверьте список интерфейсов. Если enp3s0 поднимется, попробуйте пинговать какой-нибудь IP. Сначала - в локалке, а потом - внешний.

Comment: nmcli поставь )